# Is it possible to build tensorboard without tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorboard

TensorBoard is a good tool for visualization, but currently it's build together with TensorFlow, that means I have to install TF to use TB.

I've found some hint to build it alone, from TensorBoard's document:

`bazel build tensorflow/tensorboard:tensorboard`

So my question is, is it possible to build a `.whl` file of TensorBoard like the TensorFlow does:
`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`.

And user can just using pip install from a `.whl` file which is super easy.

Comment: https://github.com/dmlc/tensorboard